# Update extension using zip file

Tags: component, extensions, update

I'm developing a component for Joomla 3.6.4. The component includes some custom SQL tables.

Now I'd like to add more tables in another version of the same component, but it seems like there's no way to update a component using a ZIP-file.   Correct?

If I try to install the component anew, it runs the old SQL install script, and causes primary key errors. Any tips would be helpful. Thank you.

**Edit**: My installation SQL code contains `INSERT` statements that caused problems with primary key collisions. These lines should only be executed once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean when you say: "it seems like there's no way to update a component using a ZIP-file".

Usually you create your extension's package. 
In your 
`myextension.xml` file you have:

```
<install type="component" version="1.5" method="upgrade">
```

Always use `method="upgrade"`

Then later in your `myextension.xml` you define your install.php file:

```
<installfile>install.myextension.php</installfile>
```

Then in your `install.myextension.php` you write your code that you wanna run during the installation/update of your extension - do all checking about existing installation and the version of it, and conditionally run code to apply any changes - including alterations to the database tables - changes which usually you include in a `install.sql` file.

Your sql file will have your DB statements - for example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__myextension_table` (...);
```

### Update: `INSERT`'s

For the case of using your `INSERTs` in your existing tables that already have the same values, your can modify your `INSERT` sql statements to:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO mytable
    (pK, field1, field2)
VALUES
    (1, val1, val2),
    (2, val3, val4),
    (3, val5, val6);
```

The `INSERT IGNO` will skip any items with Duplicate primary key.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I also had `INSERT` statements in my SQL installation code, which caused the problems.

Comment: @OlleHärstedt - so your issue is how to insert records again in the previous tables, or it is solved now for you? In any case I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, did not know about `INSERT INGORE`, good tip! Just one more question: Did you also use SQL update files with version numbers, like `1.0.1.sql`? I thought that if your version number is higher than previous, the `install.sql` will not be run, correct?